# How to share static class variables between files?

Tags: python

I was trying to share data via static class between two modules. Should've been pretty simple, but it turns out I'm hitting some kind of gotcha. Here's the code.

**testa.py**

```
class Tc:
    a = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import testb
    print(Tc.a)
```

**testb.py**

```
import testa

print(testa.Tc.a)
testa.Tc.a = 1

print(testa.Tc.a)
```

Run the command

> python testa.py

The expected out put was

```
0
1
1
```

but I' getting

```
0
1
0
```

Whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `testa` is executed and it defines the `Tc` class and imports `testb`
- `testb` imports `testa`.
- since `testa` is never been *imported* it is executed and a new `Tc` class is created
- `testb` continues printing `0` and incrementing `testa.Tc` for the imported `testa`
- the running `testa` continues printing the value of its `Tc.a` counter which is still zero.

When you run a file its module name is `__main__` (you are even checking it in a conditional inside `testa`!) while during imports the names are always the name of the module. Hence the duplication. If you want to avoid this you should really use 3 separate files, one that is run and imports `testa` and `testb` which imports `testa`.

Answer (score 2):

When your code hits `import testb`, it has a `class Tc` in memory, but the module is not done being created yet. `testb` then imports `testa` again, which is not yet cached because it’s not done creating yet, so is imported again and another `Tc` is being created.

TL;DR: Don’t do circular imports.